# Static Libraries and the App Store Review Process

Tags: iphone, app-store

I using a self compiled Obj-C Library in two of my iPhone Apps. Now, I want to send one of my apps to the App Store Review Team. What's the best pratice here? They might be some problems if I'm going to send it without the library source code.

Any experiences to share?

Thanks,
Henrik

Comment: Are they (L)GPL-licenced libraries or similar?

Comment: nope... just a self created shared library for common code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using static libraries in your app is fine, as long as those libraries don't violate the terms and conditions of the developer agreement. In short, as long as they don't use any private APIs or do anything sneaky, then there shouldn't be any problem.

My own apps use several static libraries, and all of them have been approved.

Comment: did you had to attach the source code of the static library?!

Comment: No, the static libraries should just be used in your project to link against during compilation. After that, you only need to submit your own application bundle.

Comment: @Henrik - Yes, there is no need to provide any source code for any aspect of your application.  The only exception would be if you were using GPL (or possibly LGPL) licensed libraries, in which case you'd need to make your own application's source code available publicly under the same license.  Even then, you wouldn't need to submit that source to Apple.